# Show menu bar during page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

today I visited the website . I realised, that when I click on a link, the menu bar shows the whole time during loading and building the new page. How do I achieve this?

In my opinion, this looks really sweet and I'd like to implement that as well.

Cheers

Comment: That could be the page pausing and then loading or just the animation taking time

Comment: It's a Single Page Application (SPA). It's a concept which affects how you build the site from the ground up.

Comment: Have you tried to use their code in dev tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are using CSS for Fade-in transition. You need to add class '.fade-in' and once content is loaded then add another class '.anim' to show content. See example below:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById('target').classList.add('anim');
}, 1000);
```

```css
.fade-in.anim {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.fade-in {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>estibulum semper, odio in scelerisque luctus, ex urna tristique purus, nec auctor lectus tellus pharetra nisl. Nam vehicula quis odio in ornare. Phasellus pulvinar, justo vitae tempus porta, nulla nibh suscipit ipsum, vel scelerisque metus ex ut magna.
  Morbi facilisis nisi eget nisi sollicitudin auctor. Proin lacinia turpis a porttitor varius. Maecenas eu ante et arcu vulputate iaculis eget non metus. Morbi elementum magna a facilisis pellentesque. Etiam sodales euismod imperdiet. Sed blandit vitae
  leo ut condimentum.</p>
<p id="target" class="fade-in">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent vehicula mauris dui, a consectetur nunc volutpat ultrices. Nam dapibus sagittis diam eu ultricies. Cras et pharetra nisi. Duis vel nisl et tellus venenatis laoreet ut sit amet purus. Pellentesque
  ullamcorper augue nulla, sit amet scelerisque eros condimentum quis. Vivamus sit amet felis gravida, consectetur purus eu, aliquet nunc. Nam nec mauris ut eros malesuada iaculis in a diam. Nunc imperdiet leo id sapien iaculis, a pretium est pharetra.
  Integer convallis erat nec velit lobortis pharetra. Curabitur sed metus interdum, vulputate ipsum quis, blandit quam. Etiam odio leo, semper sed varius ut, luctus at augue. Mauris viverra, mauris id rhoncus posuere, ex purus sollicitudin mi, ut aliquam
  augue felis ac elit. Mauris tincidunt eleifend orci elementum rutrum. Donec ultricies lorem at imperdiet efficitur. Mauris condimentum euismod enim, ut pulvinar tortor hendrerit ac.</p>
```

I will recommend you to view the source code of the website in debugger and learn :)

Comment: Thanks! I already looked through the source code, but to be honest, I was too lazy to take the time. They had all those typo3 crap in there, I had to beautify the scripts and so on. I guessed I'll just ask :)

Comment: Yes I thought so. If you liked my solution then can you accept it and close the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Angular js](https://angularjs.org/) and Rest API to refresh the view and data respectively

Comment: Search google with keyword 'Banana Monkey Jungle Solution'. He is asking for 'banana' and you are offering a gorilla holding the banana and the entire jungle :)

Comment: Thanks! I didnt use React, Angular and so on until yet. I mostly only used PHP Frameworks...

Answer (score 0):

The css-tricks.com has an excellent screencast on that, have a look at:

[Best Practices with Dynamic Content](http://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/85-best-practices-dynamic-content/)

Answer (score 0):

This is an so called "Single Page Application" ->https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application

Just some visible parts, the menu in this case, are sent with the initial request. The rest of the page is loaded asynchronously loaded via javascript. If you click on a link, it's not a new request inclusive refresh. Only the changing parts get refreshed.

You can achieve this with vanilla javascript or jQuery. But there are some very nice frameworks dedicated to this matter. Angular, React, etc.

Comment: No, it is not SPA. Did you get chance to look at the source code of website?

Comment: Thanks! I didnt use React, Angular and so on until yet. I mostly only used PHP Frameworks...

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this easily by using any Javascript framework like React, AngularJS or Angular (2).

An example in Angular is the following:

```
<app-menu></app-menu>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

Where the **app-menu** and **app-footer** tags will always be displayed (template for the menu and footer respectively) and the content of your app will dynamically change inside of your **router-outlet** tag.

Comment: Thanks! I didnt use React, Angular and so on until yet. I mostly only used PHP Frameworks...